# insert comma seprated values to database with validation models

Tags: php, database, laravel

i have a input fields to insert names to the database at the moment it works like every time i enter one name  it inserts and does not allow duplications the name but i want to enter multiple names comma separated this si what i have at the moment

front end

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('store.names')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="names"
                       class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Add New Name
                </label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="names" type="text"
                           class="form-control @error('names') is-invalid @enderror" name="names"
                           value="{{ old('names') }}" autocomplete="names" autofocus>

                    @error('names')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Add Names
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validation = Names::create($this->validateRequest());

        return back()->with('message','Added'));
    }

   private function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'names' => 'required|min:2|unique:Names',
        ]);
    }
```

[image]
what this does is it inserts names of one person at a time how can i insert multiple people with comma separated with the validations intact

but this iss what i need
[image]

i have figured it needs to be somthing like this

```
    $searchString = ',';

    if( strpos($request->names;, $searchString) !== false )
    {
      // insert in to db separately 
    }else{
        $names= Names::create($this->validateRequest());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could override `prepareForValidation` to preprocess the data. In this case, it would split the string by your delimiter. Then you can apply array validation using the `rules` method or your own explicit validation call.

```
protected function prepareForValidation() {
    $this->replace(['names' => explode(',', $this->names)]);
}

public function rules() {
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:2|unique:Names',
        'names.*' => 'name'
    ];
}
```

Comment: i dont really understand how i will imlement this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode() PHP function to split the string given by the input field into an array. The array will give you more flexibility to store multiple names.

Example:

```
explode(", ", "peter, jhon, pete");
```

Adapt this to your code and you'll be fine!

For more informations about the explode() function you can read the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php